# The confusing Wikipedia article about Euler's equation of rotation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, moment-of-inertia

Here is an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)#Motivation_and_derivation) from Wikipedia on Euler's equations. In the derivation of those equations, I find the torque $\mathbf M$ quite confusing. There are two torques there -- $\mathbf M$ and $\mathbf M_{in}$, but I cannot see what's the difference between them. Apparently they are both torques in inertial frames. Since we have this relation according to the article,
$$
\left(\frac{d\mathbf{L}}{dt}\right)_\mathrm{rot}+
\boldsymbol\omega\times\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{M},
$$
we have $\mathbf M = \frac{d\mathbf L}{dt}|_{in}=\mathbf M_{in}$. This doesn't seem to be right. Also, I have no idea what the so-called "rotation tensor" $\mathbf Q$ is. What's going on?

To be clear, Apparently, $\mathbf M$ and $\mathbf M_{in}$ are the same vector written in different frames. However, I have no idea what $\mathbf Q$ is. Is the position vector $\mathbf r$ also transformed by $\mathbf Q$ in the same way? ($\mathbf r=Q \mathbf r_{in}$?)

Comment: $\mathbf{M}$ is the torque in the rotating and thus *non*-inertial frame. It is *not* equal to $\frac{d\mathbf L}{dt}|_\text{in}$.

Comment: Because the equation is given in components of the rotating system, you must transfer the torque components $M=\left( M\right) _{rot}=Q\left( M\right) _{in}$ from initial to rot system

Comment: Please read my edit - I was not clear enough - in fact, I just want to know whether $\mathbf M$ transforms the same way as $\mathbf r$.

Comment: @Ma Jose , yes M is transferring as the position vector r